# Asset.car and app icons missing in ipa that was built with msbuild

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, msbuild, app-store-connect

We have a Xamarin iOS app. After migrating the app icons from Info.plist to asset catalog as described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/deprecated/app-icons/#Migrating_from_Info.plist_to_Asset_Catalogs) we built the ipa on our Jenkins build node using `msbuild`. During the upload to iTunes Connect with `fastlane deliver` we get the following errors:

```
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon20x20'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon29x29'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon40x40'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon60x60'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon76x76'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon83.5x83.5'"
ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
```

After inspecting the ipa file we found out that it does not contain the Asset.car and app icon image files. An ipa that was built on a different Jenkins build node (but with no difference regarding the installed versions of Visual Studio, Xamarin components and Xcode) contains the Asset.car and app icon image files and this ipa can be uploaded successfully to iTunes Connect.

So we consider the error messages to be correct and tried to analyze why `msbuild` does not include the Asset.car and app icon image files on the first build node. We set the verbosity level of `msbuild` to *diagnostic* and compared the output logs from each build nodes and could not find a difference. We still keep getting the error after [uninstalling Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/), Visual Studio and Xcode and reinstalling each of them.

Do you have any ideas what could interfere with `msbuild` so that the ipa is not built correctly and leaves out the Asset.car and app icons files?

This is our Xamarin configuration on both build nodes:

```
=== Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac ===

Version 7.3.3 (build 12)
Installation UUID: 00428305-dedb-4567-8ef4-0cad0c20a275
Runtime:
    Mono 5.4.1.7 (2017-06/e66d9abbb27) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

    Package version: 504010007

=== NuGet ===

Version: 4.3.1.4445

=== .NET Core ===

Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Version: 2.0.0
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/Sdks
SDK Version: 2.0.0
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.6.0
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 9.2 (13772)
Build 9C40b

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 11.6.1.4 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: db807ec9
Branch: xcode9.2
Build date: 2018-01-10 16:45:48-0500

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 8.1.5.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /private/var/lib/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        4.4    (API level 19)
        4.4.87 (API level 20)
        5.0    (API level 21)
        5.1    (API level 22)
        6.0    (API level 23)
        7.0    (API level 24)
        7.1    (API level 25)
        8.0    (API level 26)

SDK Tools Version: 25.2.5
SDK Platform Tools Version: 27.0.1
SDK Build Tools Version: 26.0.2

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 4.0.0.216 (Visual Studio Community)

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.4.0
Hash: b3f92f9
Branch: master
Build date: Fri, 19 Jan 2018 22:00:34 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 703030012
Git revision: b07492f1e48be596bad92dc4b7a3bc2d128ed0f9
Build date: 2018-01-30 13:15:55-05
Xamarin addins: 7c8f967d67207118dd99a1d0cc9c228045b30c5f
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-d15-5

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.13.3
Darwin 17.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0
    Sun Dec 17 09:19:54 PST 2017
    root:xnu-4570.41.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

=== Enabled user installed addins ===

Internet of Things (IoT) development (Preview) 7.1
```

Comment: Have you ever found the solution? I'm facing exactly the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, we did not find a solution for this issue.

Comment: Thanks. So the only solution was to set up another build node?

Comment: And if you still have this not working node please check if you have following line:

Building target "_CopyResourcesToBundle" partially, because some output files are out of date with respect to their input files.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have access to the build node with this error any longer. Setting up a new build node might does not solve this problem, it just did not happen to show up on a different build node with the same configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, making a new node didn't help. Thanks for the info.